# Does every preorder induce a partial order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

A (non-strict) preorder is defined as a **reflexive and transitive** homogenous relation; a (non-strict) partial order is defined as a **reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive** homogenous relation.

Clearly, every partial order is a preorder but not every preorder needs to be a partial order (cf. [1]). However, it seems to me that every preorder *induces* a partial order via the following construction:

- Every preorder induces a strict preorder (an irreflexive, transitive relation). [2]
- Every strict preorder is a strict partial order (an irreflexive, transitive, antisymmetric relation). [3]
- Every strict partial order induces a (non-strict) partial order. [4]

Is that correct or where did I go wrong? I appreciate any help you can provide.

---

Sources:

[1] [StackExchange: Preorders vs partial orders - Clarification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992277/preorders-vs-partial-orders-clarification)

[2] [Wikipedia: Strict preorder induced by a preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder#Preorders_and_strict_preorders)

[3] [Wikipedia on preorders:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder#Formal_definition) "A binary relation is a strict preorder if and only if it is a strict partial order."

[4] [Wikipedia on partial orders:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Correspondence_of_strict_and_non-strict_partial_order_relations) "Conversely, a strict partial order $<$ on $P$ may be converted to a non-strict partial order".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easy way to get a partial order:

Starting with a preorder $R$,

for each element $x$, put into the equivalence class of $x$ every element $y$ such that both $xRy$ and $yRx$.

You immediately have a partial order on the equivalence classes.

---

Now I refer to your steps.

Technically, every preorder induces a strict preorder **unless all the elements are equivalent**.

With that qualification, yes, your way works.

For illustration:

Suppose there are three elements in the preorder $a\equiv b$ and $a<c$.

The obvious way gives a partial order with two elements, $[a,b]$ being less than $[c]$.

Your way gives rise to a partial order with three elements, such that $a$ is less than $c$ and such that $b$ is less than $c$. The new partial order doesn't say anything that relates $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly seems like a more straightforward way to get there.

I suppose the partial order on the set of equivalence classes then canonically induces a partial order on the original set via $x \preceq y \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad [x] \preceq [y]$, right?

Comment: @Maxas No it doesn't. The relation you retrieve that way is the same preorder you started with.

Comment: @amrsa Yes, I just realized $\preceq$ defined that way on the original set would not be antisymmetric. That means that the procedure sketched by Chris doesn't produce a partial order on the set itself, unlike what I presumably outlined in my original post. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Maxas No, you are right. It's just a partial order on the quotient set.

Comment: @amrsa Do you know if the one in the original post works?

Comment: @Maxas I think that section on wikipedia is rather confusing, although they try to sort out that confusion, I don't think they really succeed. It seems to me that when $a \sim b$, in the strict preorder, which is also a strict order, neither $a<b$ nor $b<a$, so a lot of the relation is lost. Yes, that will give you a partial order, but you can also get one with more of the original, by replacing each set of equivalent elements with a poset (even a chain). What they seem to do is to replace it with an anti-chain. That's all right, but it's not the closest to the original relation.

Comment: @Maxas I edited to take account of your question.

Comment: @amrsa Thank you both for your answers, that settles my question!